# How can I organize Role Based Access Control (?) in my scenario?

Tags: mysql, data-structures

I have a database where there are products grouped by categories.

When a user registers, he selects a category, which cannot be changed. The user will be able to perform some actions only on the products of that category, and some other actions on products of other categories as well. E.g. a user can comment on a product only in his category, or put a like on a product in another category.

A user with "superpowers" becomes a Moderator. He can do everything a user does, plus the ability to change something made by another user. E.g. he can modify a comment written by another user but always in reference to a product of the category he belongs to.

Then there are the Admins, who are Moderators who, however, can work independently of the category.

How can I set up the tables for this scenario?

Comment: It's going to depend on what DBMS you are using.  Most professional DBMS's have built-in features for this kind of thing.  You can "roll you own" if you want, but you will still have to get the current user's identity as a starting point, and this is different for every DBMS.

Comment: I'm using mysql

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know MySql well enough to answer this question, so hopefully someone else will be able to.

Comment: This is a pretty broad topic. Where are you getting stuck? Sounds to me you might just need some if statements that check which category a user picked, and a `role` field on a users table.